# How to retrieve a list of data(model) from AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin

Like in android we retrieve LiveData<List> from mainview model but i want a list of Model, like List not livedata or i want to loop through the all values of the table of the database.

Comment: Plz add more description or snippet for your code

Comment: Actually I have a contacts app with room database, this part is working fine, but I fetch the CallLog and I want to match each phone number from the CallLog with the phone numbers from room database with PhoneUtils.compare(string number1,string number2) thats why i need i list of my room database but as i have LiveData from the room database, thats why i can't iterate throug the all data in room database.

Answer (score 0):

To use live data with **Room DB**, you need to use **Coroutines' Flow**.

**MyViewModel**

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val list: LiveData<List<String>> = ListRoomDB.dao.getList().asLiveData()

    ...
}
```

**Dao**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface Dao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM string_table")
    fun getList(): Flow<List<String>>
    
    ...
}
```

[This tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0) (section 7 -) should walk you along all the steps to properly do that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but problem is a bit kinda different you can read here,Actually I have a contacts app with room database, this part is working fine, but I fetch the CallLog and I want to match each phone number from the CallLog with the phone numbers from room database with PhoneUtils.compare(string number1,string number2) thats why i need i list of my room database but as i have LiveData from the room database, thats why i can't iterate throug the all data in room database.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. Please Edit your question to make it as clear for other users.